# Sharepoint Online - Site Data Collection change

Tags: sharepoint

I am currently trying to disable a OneDrive for my organisation. It works pretty well for new users, but old ones got access. I worked out one solution - when I take away collection admin rights user cannot use OneDrive anymore.

But I have 1000 users, and I will die changing permissions by hand, therefore is there any script to set all site collection admins to one person?

I mean those settings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A63RZ.png

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable OneDrive and don't want anyone to access it, instead of changing permissions, you can lock all OneDrive sites via PowerShell code:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking
 
#Parameters
$AdminCenterURL = "https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com"
 
Try {
    #Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Center
    Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminCenterURL -Credential (Get-Credential)
 
    #Get All OneDrive for Business Sites in the Tenant
    $OneDriveSites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL -includepersonalsite $True -Filter "Url -like '-my.sharepoint.com/personal/'"
      
    #Loop through each OneDrive Site
    Foreach($Site in $OneDriveSites)
    {
        Set-SPOSite -Identity $Site -LockState "NoAccess"
        Write-host "Scanning site:"$Site.Url "is locked"-f Yellow
 
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error locking Sites:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Result is:
[image]

After that, when users try to access OneDrive, a 403 error will be returned.

About [Set-SPOSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps)